# Spellcheck an HTML file in the terminal

Tags: command-line, sublime-text, spell-checking

I have been trying to find a way to spellcheck my HTML file's content in Sublime for quality control.  I have referenced several articles referring to `aspell` but after installation and trying to run through HTML files I am having to strip out all tags and its complicated trying to go through all HTML files on a package/project level.  Is there a spellcheck tool that I can script with in the terminal that will ignore the tags and check the content?  Any other ideas for better implementation I am for it

Comment: Care to use vim?

Comment: never used it before so if you have some documentation to look at I will give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Vim's spell checking is smart enough to distinguish between HTML tags and their contents:

[image]

Spell checking is not enabled by default, and can be enabled by:

```
:set spell
```

The documentation for spell checking in Vim can be browsed using [`:help spell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spell-quickstart).

---

If you have never use Vim before, it can be a bit ... daunting. First install a more full-featured version:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Then run `gvimtutor` to learn the basics of Vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **aspell** in the command line:

```
aspell -H check your_file.html
```

the -H option makes it HTML aware.

if you don't have it just install by:

```
sudo apt install aspell
```