# What's Ubuntu's default terminal spell checker?

Tags: command-line, spell-checking

There's a program that comes with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by default which is run totally in the terminal and will spell check a text file.  But I have trouble remembering what the program is called.  What is this program, and how do I run it on `~/Documents/file`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ubuntu apparently comes with *two* spell-check programs by default:

```
$ apropos spell
aspell (1)           - interactive spell checker
aspell-autobuildhash (8) - Autobuilding aspell hash files for some dicts
aspell-import (1)    - import old personal dictionaries into GNU Aspell
enchant (1)          - a spellchecker
enchant-lsmod (1)    - Show information about available spell-checking module...
```

[`enchant`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/enchant.1) is also an `ispell`-compatible spell-checker, and is listed in [the ISO manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest), so it is installed by default.

And though it is not installed by default, Vim's full-fledged versions also support [spell-checking](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spell), and do better in more complex files (for example, [spell-checking only text in HTML](https://askubuntu.com/a/612489/158442)).

Comment: Muru, great point, I didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 16):

The program I needed was `aspell`.  It's very simple to run:

```
aspell check ~/Documents/file
```

It will automatically check the file for spelling errors based on the locale set.  More information about it can be found [in the man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/aspell).

Hope this helps someone!